# Mac M1 and Pyaudio. ||PaMacCore (AUHAL)|| AUHAL component not found

Tags: python, homebrew, apple-m1, pyaudio, portaudio

I´m using a Macbook M1 and I'm trying to use Pyaudio on Python, but the following error appears:

```
|**|PaMacCore (AUHAL)|| AUHAL component not found.** .... stream = audio.open(format=FORMAT, channels=CHANNELS, ...  stream = PyAudio.Stream(self, *args, **kwargs) ...   self._stream = pa.open(**arguments) ... **OSError: [Errno -9999] Unanticipated host error**
```

I tried to uninstall and install Homebrew, PyAudio & port audio several times. I followed this suggestion as well https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252638887. But still without success.

I would like to know if anyone knows how to solve this problem or has any suggestions. Or if someone can record by Python without any issue.

Note: The permission to use the microphone is activated through systems, privacy and security.

Thank you.